# NDSolve in Mathematica 11

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I can't use my Mathematica 9 code in Mathematica 11 — it works in Mathematica 9, but when I run it in Mathematica 11 it shows a lot of errors
It gives me this message

> ReplaceAll::reps: {NDSolve[{(2 (ψ^′)[r])/r+(ψ^′′)[r]==0.00135103 Sinh[ψ[r]],ψ[1]==-5.,(ψ^′)[1.4938]==0.001},ψ,{r,1,1.4938},Method->{EquationSimplification->Residual}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing..

Please help me fix my code or tell me why `NDSolve` did not work in Mathematica 11?

#### Code

```
Clear["Global`*"];
(*initialize variables*)
Subscript[λ, B] = 0.714107`20;  
 a = 25;  
Z = 1000;  
Subscript[c, 0] = .2; 
η = 0.3;  
γ = Subscript[λ, B]/a;  
R = η^(-1/3);  
Subscript[n, m] = 3 η/(4 π);
Avogadro = 6.0221413`20 10^-7; 
Subscript[n, 0] = Subscript[c, 0] Avogadro a^3;  
κ2 = 8 π γ Subscript[n, 0] ; 
κ = Sqrt[κ2] ; 
ϵ = $MachineEpsilon ;

ψin[ψtest_?NumericQ] := 
 NDSolve[{ψ''[r] + 2 ψ'[r]/r == κ2 Sinh[ψ[r]] + 
     3 Z γ, ψ[1] == ψtest, ψ'[ϵ] == 
    0}, ψ, {r, ϵ, 1}, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]

ψout[ψtest_?NumericQ] := 
 NDSolve[{ψ''[r] + 
     2 ψ'[r]/r == κ2 Sinh[ψ[r]], ψ[
     1] == ψtest, ψ'[R] == 0}, ψ, {r, 1, R}, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]

ψinTry[ψtest_?
   NumericQ] := (Evaluate[ψ'[1] /. ψin[ψtest]])[[1]]

ψoutTry[ψtest_?
   NumericQ] := (Evaluate[ψ'[1] /. ψout[ψtest]])[[1]]

ψtest0 = -5;  
ψa = ψtest /. 
  FindRoot[ψinTry[ψtest] == ψoutTry[ψtest], {\
ψtest, ψtest0}];
Clear[ψtest];
ψtest0 = ψa
ψR = (Evaluate[ψ[R] /. ψout[ψa]])[[1]];
Subscript[c, s] = 
 3 Subscript[c, 
  0] η NIntegrate[(r^2) If[
     r < 1, (Evaluate[Exp[ψ[r] /. ψin[ψa]]])[[
      1]], (Evaluate[Exp[ψ[r] /. ψout[ψa]]])[[1]]], {r,
     0, R}] 

Print[NumberForm[η, 4], "  ", NumberForm[Subscript[c, s], 10], 
  "  ", NumberForm[ψR, 10]];

Clear[ψtest];
Clear[r];

yin = ψin[ψa];
yout = ψout[ψa];

ψlist = {};
Elist = {};

ψr[r_] := If[r < 1, ψ[r] /. yin[[1]], ψ[r] /. yout[[1]]];

Plot[ψr[r], {r, 0, R}, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"r/a", "ψ(r)"}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontFamily -> "Calibri", 
   FontSize -> 16}, 
 EvaluationMonitor :> AppendTo[ψlist, {r, ψr[r]}]]

Export["psi.dat", Sort[ψlist], "Table"]

Er[r_] := If[r < 1, ψ'[r] /. yin[[1]], ψ'[r] /. yout[[1]]];

Plot[Er[r], {r, 0, R}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"r/a", "E(r)"},
  BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontFamily -> "Calibri", 
   FontSize -> 16}, EvaluationMonitor :> AppendTo[Elist, {r, Er[r]}]]

Export["E.dat", Sort[Elist], "Table"]
```

Comment: `\[Psi]test` is not defined in the line `FindRoot[\[Psi]inTry[\[Psi]test]==\[Psi]outTry[\[Psi]test],{\[Psi]test,\[Psi]test0}]`  so I have no idea how this could have worked in any Mathematica version. All what you had to do is run each command in separate cell, until you see where the problem is.

Comment: You defined `\[Psi]inTry[\[Psi]test_?NumericQ]` as taking numeric. But you call it using `\[Psi]inTry[\[Psi]test]` where `\[Psi]test` is not defined. Same for `\[Psi]outTry[\[Psi]test_?NumericQ]`. Your code seems to be missing definitions.

Comment: Thank you for your help